# Custom iterator to print every second member of the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

so basically I am trying to write my own custom iterator to print every second number of an ArrayList. I populated the arraylist with ints from 0 up to 100.

But somehow it still not using my custom Iterator, oddly print out every single int in my arrayList.

Am I approaching this the wrong way?
Code:

```
public class IteratorTesting implements Iterable{
    ArrayList<Integer> rand;

    public IteratorTesting(){
        rand = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getRand(){
        return rand;
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return rand.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }

    public class MyIterator implements Iterator<Object>{
        int currentIndex=0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(currentIndex<rand.size()){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            return rand.get(currentIndex+=2);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IteratorTesting name = new IteratorTesting();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            name.getRand().add(i);
        }
        Iterator it = name.getRand().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
run:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
50
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
80
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On this line

```
Iterator it = name.getRand().iterator();
```

you've fetched the `Iterator` for the `ArrayList`, instead of your custom iterator.  So you're just iterating the list in the regular way.

Comment: But i overriden the Iterator Object.

    @Override
    public Iterator iterator() {
        return new MyIterator();
    }

Comment: No, you haven't.  You've overridden it on the `IteratorTesting` class, but not on the `ArrayList` object inside it.

Comment: name.iterator() instead

Comment: I see. It works. Thank you very much. I have been stuck on this forever.